# Mongodb count all array elements in all objects matching by criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that is log of activity on objects like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55e3fd1d7cb5ac9a458b4567"),
    "object_id" : "1",
    "activity" : [ 
        {
            "action" : "test_action",
            "time" : ISODate("2015-08-31T00:00:00.000Z")
        },
        {
            "action" : "test_action",
            "time" : ISODate("2015-08-31T00:00:22.000Z")
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55e3fd127cb5ac77478b4567"),
    "object_id" : "2",
    "activity" : [ 
        {
            "action" : "test_action",
            "time" : ISODate("2015-08-31T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55e3fd0f7cb5ac9f458b4567"),
    "object_id" : "1",
    "activity" : [ 
        {
            "action" : "test_action",
            "time" : ISODate("2015-08-30T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

If i do followoing query:

```
db.objects.find({
    "createddate": {$gte : ISODate("2015-08-30T00:00:00.000Z")},
    "activity.action" : "test_action"}
    }).count()
```

it returns count of documents containing "test_action" (3 in this set), but i need to get count of all test_actions (4 on this set). How do i do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most "performant" way to do this is to skip the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) altogther and simply [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to count. Essentially "filter" arrays get the [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of the results to [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/):

```js
db.objects.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "createddate": {
            "$gte": ISODate("2015-08-30T00:00:00.000Z")
        },
        "activity.action": "test_action"
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "count": {
            "$sum": {
                "$size": {
                    "$setDifference": [
                        { "$map": {
                            "input": "$activity",
                            "as": "el",
                            "in": {
                                "$cond": [ 
                                    { "$eq": [ "$$el.action", "test_action" ] },
                                    "$$el",
                                    false
                                ]
                            }               
                        }},
                        [false]
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Since MongoDB version 3.2 we can use [`$filter`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/), which makes this much more simple:

```js
db.objects.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "createddate": {
            "$gte": ISODate("2015-08-30T00:00:00.000Z")
        },
        "activity.action": "test_action"
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "count": {
            "$sum": {
                "$size": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$activity",
                        "as": "el",
                        "cond": {
                            "$eq": [ "$$el.action", "test_action" ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Using `$unwind` causes the documents to de-normalize and effectively creates a copy per array entry. Where possible you should avoid this due the the often extreme cost. Filtering and counting array entries per document is much faster by comparison. As is a simple `$match` and `$group` pipeline compared to many stages.

Comment: Thank you very much. Avoiding of "$unwind" is a must on large datasets. Query works like a charm. My knowledge is quite basic now and i don't actually know HOW it works yet :) But finding this out will be my homework for today)

Answer (score 9):

You can do so by using aggregation:

```
db.objects.aggregate([
    {$match: {"createddate": {$gte : ISODate("2015-08-30T00:00:00.000Z")}, {"activity.action" : "test_action"}}},
    {$unwind: "$activity"},
    {$match: {"activity.action" : "test_action"}}},
    {$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: 1}}}
])
```

This will produce a result like:

```
{
    count: 4
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but it seems it doesn't use indexes and works extremelly slow on 600k documents dataset. I have indexes for `_id`, `createddate` and `activity.action`. What else indexes should i create?

Comment: Aggregation does use an index for the $match stage (if specified at the beginning), but as Blakes Seven has said, the unwind stage causes a lot of overhead.

Comment: I have added an edit, this should make it run a bit faster

Comment: Yeah, that's good idea to filter it befor unwinding. Works much faster. Thank you!