# Mongoose Model#Aggregate function returning 0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following objects:

- User
- Event
- Ticket
- TicketPurchase

I am trying to count the number of `Tickets` in all `TicketPurchases` for a given `Event` based on a particular `Ticket.type`.

I am using the following code to try and achieve this:

**ticket.js**

```
const TicketSchema = new Schema({
    type : {type: String},
    total_quantity : {type: Number},
    price : {type: String},
    limit_per_order: {type: Number},
    start_date: {type: Date},
    end_date: {type: Date},
    description: {type: String},
    validated: {type: String, default: 'false'}
});
```

**ticketPurchase.js**

```
const TicketPurchaseSchema = new Schema({
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    event: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Event'},
    tickets: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Ticket'}],
    time_stamp: {type: Date}

});
```

**count.js**

```
var event_id = req.query.event_id;
var ticket_id = req.query.ticket_id;

Ticket.findOne({ _id: ticket_id }).exec(function(err, results) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(results); //returns ticket successfully
  TicketPurchase.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $match: {
          event: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(event_id)
        }
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: null,
          count: {
            $sum: {
              $size: {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$tickets",
                  as: "el",
                  cond: {
                    $eq: ["$$el.type", results.type]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],

    function(err, results) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(results); //number of ticket purchases
      }
    }
  );
});
```

But i keep getting the following result:

[image: count is always 0]

Count is always 0, however, i can confirm that there are Tickets in the TicketPurchase.

[image: mLad]

Also, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305897/mongodb-count-all-array-elements-in-all-objects-matching-by-criteria) suggests avoiding using $unwind.

I am still new to mongodb. Thanks in advance

Tools:

- Nodejs
- Mongoose
- mLab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage which allows you to join ticket purchase collection with ticket collection.

Add the below stage between [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

```
{"$lookup":{
  "from":"ticket",
  "localField":"tickets",
  "foreignField":"_id",
  "as":"tickets"
}}
```

Alternate and more [performant](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-21612) solution will be to use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) + [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) + [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) combination to apply the type criteria to the joined collection instead of [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/). Replace all stages after [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) with below stages.

Something like

```
{"$lookup":{
    "from":"ticket",
    "localField":"tickets",
    "foreignField":"_id",
    "as":"tickets"
}},
{"$unwind":"$tickets"},
{"$match":{"tickets.type":results.type}},
{"$count":"count"}
```

Comment: Now im getting an empty array as the result

Comment: Can you make sure you pass the correct collection name in the `from` attribute of lookup stage ? May be it is `tickets` instead of `ticket`

Comment: goodness. That was it. I changed it to `ticketPurchase` when it was supposed to be the name of the array within `ticketPurchase`. Thanks a lot sir. Much appreciated